# How to respawn thread in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to have the `threadPoolExecutor` spy on the thread and respawn it if it reaches timeout threshold?

For example

```
ThreadPoolExecutor myThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
            10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000));

myThreadPool.submit(new MyTask());


public MyTask() {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // do something, this sometimes hangs, how do thread communicate to myThreadPool that it needs to be respawn?
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: So you need a scheduler?

Comment: MyTask is not supposed to communicate with the executor, and the executor does not run the tasks more than once. Maybe you need a Scheduler (but that  just reruns tasks periodically, even when they finished in time)? Or have whatever submitted the task check on the progress (probably via a scheduler) and resubmit if necessary?